# Server static files from FTP server using NGINX

Tags: nginx, ftp

I have a local network, on which there are some old insecure services. I use nginx reverse proxy with client certificates authentication as safe entrypoint to this local network from the Internet. Till now I used it only to proxy HTTP servers using

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.123.45:80/;
    }
```

and everything works fine.

But now I would like to serve static files, that are accessible through FTP on a local server, I tried simply:

```
    location /foo {
        proxy_pass ftp://user:password@192.168.100.200:5000/;
    }
```

but that doesn't work, and I could not find anything that would simply proxy HTTP request to FTP request.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nginx doesn't support proxying to FTP servers.  At best, you can proxy the socket... and this is a real hassle with regular old FTP due to it opening new connections on random ports every time a file is requested.

What you can probably do instead is create a FUSE mount to that FTP server on some local path, and serve that path with Nginx like normal.  To that end, [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) is one tool for this.  Tutorial:  https://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem

(Note:  For security and reliability, it's strongly recommended you migrate away from FTP when possible.  Consider [SSH/SFTP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server) instead.)

Comment: Well, just keep in mind.. SSH/SFTP will perform worse according to the security level added (encrypted connection).

Comment: @HasanAlsawadi Anyone who actually cared about performance wouldn't be doing this sort of proxying in the first place.  Also, I challenge your assertion.  Doing this over SSH, only one TCP connection is necessary, whereas with FTP a separate connection is created for every transfer.  The overhead from crypto is hardly anything, and is often offloaded to hardware.

Comment: Thanks mate, make sense! A benchmark on this would be yummy, will add it to my to-dos ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use nfs mount first you need install on ftp server: example in Debian11

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

Than on /etc/exports you can sett allow share your dir to ip server

```
/home/sharedir ip.ip.ip.ip(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=0,anongid=0)
```

On Nginx server install

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

and mount dir from first server

```
mount /mnt/myremotesharedir ip.ip.ip.ip:/home/sharedir
```

Now you can use in nginx path to /home/sharedir as root or alias

```
location /foo {
    root /home/sharedir/foo;
}
```